# How can I prevent this TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of null

Tags: reactjs, null, typeerror, render, use-effect

I am initializing two states with null and setting them with data from the useEffect hook. However in a different component, I am getting the error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of null on the currentVideo state. However, it should have been set during the initial useEffect render. How can I set the currentVideo state and prevent the type error.

```
function App() {
  const [videoList, setVideoList] = useState(null);
  const [currentVideo, setCurrentVideo] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`${BACK_PORT}/videos` || `${LOCAL_PORT}/videos`)
      .then(function (response) {
        let videos = response.data.map((item, index) => {
          return { path: item, id: index, isAggressive: true };
        });
        setVideoList(videos);
        setCurrentVideo(videos[0]);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {});
  }, []);

  return videoList ? (<Component />) : <div>Loading</div>
```

Comment: Could you please share the part of the code where you're trying to read that ``x`` property ? ...

Comment: Try adding ! after currentVideo in the second component . Like currentVideo!